# How can I get the sum of every instance of itemColor & itemSize with each other. I am using Oracle by the way

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to count every instance of black in size 2, black in size 1, white in size 5 etc. This is the table -

```
create table inventoryItem (
       itemNum    varchar(10) not null
              references itemType(itemNum) on delete cascade,
       code   varchar(20) not null,
       qtyInstock float       not null,
       itemColor  varchar(15),
       itemSize   float,
       primary key (itemNum, code)
);
```

This is the closest I got -

```
SELECT DISTINCT itemColor, SUM(qtyInstock) 
FROM inventoryItem
GROUP BY itemColor;

SELECT DISTINCT itemSize, SUM(qtyInstock) 
FROM inventoryItem
GROUP BY itemSize;
```

This shows the count of how many sizes there are and then another count of how many colors there are. I am not too sure how to go about this query. Any help is always appreciated, thank you!

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT when you do GROUP BY raises many people's eyebrows. (Your GROUP BY returns no duplicates, i.e. no need to to SELECT DISTINCT.)

Comment: Why is itemSize a float column? I'd consider integer instead.

Comment: Hint: You can GROUP BY several columns.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't supply any sample data or expected output try this

```
create table inventory (
 itemcolor varchar2(10),
 itemsize integer
);


insert into inventory values ( 'red',  1 );
insert into inventory values ( 'red',  1 );
insert into inventory values ( 'red',  1 );

insert into inventory values ( 'red',  2 );
insert into inventory values ( 'red',  2 );

insert into inventory values ( 'black',  5 );

insert into inventory values ( 'black',  6 );
insert into inventory values ( 'black',  6 );
insert into inventory values ( 'black',  6 );
insert into inventory values ( 'black',  6 );

SELECT itemcolor, itemsize, count(*) as quantity 
FROM inventory 
GROUP BY itemcolor, itemsize
ORDER BY itemcolor, itemsize;

ITEMCOLOR   ITEMSIZE    QUANTITY
black   5   1
black   6   4
red 1   3
red 2   2
```